# IAP paymentQueue:updatedTransactions directly gives the transaction status as purchased

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase

I am recently facing the issue of **Storekit's** `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions` unexpected behaviour. The issue is as soon as I add payment into the transaction queue using below code,

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

without asking for apple's sandbox credentials or without any purchase process the loop directly gives the purchased state.

Is anyone facing this kind of issue. Or any idea of this? Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it is transaction for this exact payment, but not for previous some just fetched from queue?

Comment: @Asperi, what I found is when I purchase at first time the apple purchase flow is working proper by asking credentials, purchase confirmation, success alert, etc. I am finishing transactions when its completed or restored. But when I go for second purchase it only enters into purchasing state and previous transaction goes to the purchased state. This time no any apple purchase flow occurs. And then every time when app runs that pending transaction with purchasing state enters into loop and nothing happens further.

Comment: @Asperi, do you have any idea how to fix this kind of issue?

Comment: I did not observe such kind of issue. It is probably something either in product configuration on ASC or in purchasing logic of your app.